# Spring @Lazy annotation not working with kotlin

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I'm trying to lazily initialize a bean in a spring boot app with Kotlin.

I have a spring @Configuration file where i have a lazily annotated bean:

```
@Lazy
@Bean
open fun createSomething(): Something {
    return Something("yo")
}
```

I have a rest controller where i have lazily autowired the bean

```
@Lazy
@Autowired
private lateinit var something: Something
```

I'm accessing a variable in the class in one of the `@RequestMapping`s

```
println(something.thing)
```

I've added logs in the `@Bean` method and confirmed that the bean isn't getting eagerly initialized. The problem is the it's not getting initialized even on access. The class is a simple open class.

```
open class Something(val thing: String)
```

The bean initialization never happens. I don't know what i'm doing wrong.

Here are the versions:

> Java: 1.8.0_191
>
> Kotlin: 1.1.60
>
> Spring Boot: 2.0.2.RELEASE

I don't know if it's some sort of version problem or i'm doing something in using the lazy bean. Appreciate the help.

Comment: You are using several years old Kotlin. It could be a good idea to update to 1.3.21 for example

Answer (score 0):

Update your Kotlin compiler. [`@Lazy`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Lazy.html) works fine for me in Kotlin v1.3.x.